# coreML scikit learn model returning integer probabilities

Tags: python, ios, scikit-learn, coreml, coremltools

I have trained a scikit learn `RandomForestClassifier` model and converted it to the iOS coreML format with `coremltools.converters.sklearn`. The model has 4 classes in the target variable. When trained the target variable is `string` as opposed to `int`.

When I execute the model on iOS the class probabilities output are 4 integer values. How do I interpret these? Are they likelihoods? I would have expected probabilities that sum to 1.

Note: When I do the same with a 2 class model (target variable is `int`) I get the class probabilities that sum to 1.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Show the code and some sample data and output

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I am not in posession of the iOS side of things but I was wondering if anyone could provide insight. Are you using these tools?

Comment: rather than down-vote could you suggest and alternative venue for this discussion? there really isn't a lot of literature or documentation out there on this.

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).